# how to solve pgadmin4 Increment value cannot be empty

Tags: pgadmin

my pgadmin4's version is V4.5.
modify table warning me  Increment value cannot be empty.
but pgadmin4  document dont have increment[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e41Ws.png)

but my pgadmin4 have a tag that named identity,it have a increment value input,but can input anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug has been fix on version 4.6.
Check out [release notes 4.6](https://github.com/postgres/pgadmin4/blob/master/docs/en_US/release_notes_4_6.rst) and issue #4160